# How to make image and text inline?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

My HTML code is

```
<div id="policydoc" >
    <img src="images/arrowdown.png" />   
    <div id="policytext">Policy</div>  
    <img src="images/arrowdown.png" />   
    <div id="policytext">Receipt</div>  
</div>
```

i want to make arrow down image and Policy text to align left side and second arrowdown image and receipt text to align right but in the same line.I want all these two images and two texts in the same line.Can any one help me to arrange it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: plz post this question in CSS section. Use image as background image & use different class for different positions.

Comment: You have two elements with the same id..  This is invalid html.  Use classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you want [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/CCaYK/)

**html**

```
<div id="policydoc" >
    <div class="left">
        <img src="images/arrowdown.png" />   
        <div class="policytext">Policy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">    
        <img src="images/arrowdown.png" />   
        <div  class="policytext">Receipt</div> 
    </div>
</div>​
```

**css**

```
.policytext{
  display: inline-block;
}
.left{
   float:left;
}
.right{
   float:right;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Add CSS like this

```
#policydoc img {
float: left;
} 

#policydoc #policytext{
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Dipaks noted, you should use `display: inline-block;`, however, you also currently have invalid html markup:

```
<div id="policydoc" >
    <img src="images/arrowdown.png" />   
    <div class="policytext">Policy</div>  
    <img src="images/arrowdown.png" />   
    <div class="policytext">Receipt</div>  
</div>
```

This is how your html should look; if you are going to use ids, they must be **unique**.  Your css file should of course then contain the following, if not something similar:

```
div.policytext {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/VWZyt/)

Answer (score -1):

You are using `div` wrong and don't fully understand the paradigm that divs are created around if you are trying to place elements in-line using divs.

A `div` is like an element `span`. I think of `span` as spanning across the screen (I'm an English speaker, so left to right). Anyhow, `span` was specifically created for elements in-line, and `div` for blocks.

Really you could place `div` inline, however, you would really be bending HTML in a way that feels unnatural. IMHO an in-line `div` is a freak of nature, and it should be beaten until it turns into a `span`.